# Unable to get correct behaviour from Ansible boolean variable

Tags: ansible, boolean, conditional-statements, case-when, negation

Jenkins has a Boolean parameter `mycheck` which gets passed to ansible playbook like below:

```
ansible-playbook -i /var/myserver.hosts /var/testplay.yml -e mycheck=$mycheck
```

The above translates to the below when the checkbox is unchecked:

```
ansible-playbook -i /var/myserver.hosts /var/testplay.yml -e mycheck=False

cat /var/testplay.yml

- debug:
    msg: "mycheck is True"
  when: not mycheck
```

However, the above debug gets skipped when I was expecting the `when` condition to be true and print.

Can you please suggest why `not mycheck` is not translated to "true" and the `when` condition met ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause:
This is caused due to the datatype issue, By default, ansible treats any variable passed via extra-vars as Unicode string instead of associating a boolean class to the text that is passed.

Solution:
Your initial command of execution should be modified to below
`ansible-playbook -i /var/myserver.hosts /var/testplay.yml -e '{ mycheck: True }'`

Comment: passed `-e '{ mycheck=false }'` but now it is giving me the the following error:     `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'not mycheck and file_perm == \"\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (not mycheck and file_perm == \"\"): 'mycheck' is undefined `

Comment: with `-e '{ mycheck: false }'` it works while with `-e '{ mycheck=false }'` it fails. Can you suggest a solution for `-e '{ mycheck=false }'` ?

Comment: I dont think it works that way, with respect to the syntax